# How to add a gmail suite account to mac

Tags: mac, gmail, google-workspace

When I try to add an account I get a message prompt saying

> Google requires completing authentication in Safari.

Which opens an incognito safari browser window with a google login, after entering my email and sending, I get a blank screen. Copying the URL doesn't work since mac expects the validation to happen via the popup window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading this, perhaps you ended up going over the discussion boards that cover this issue without any success. In my case, I figured out that the private popup comes with javascript disabled by default, breaking the login process after sending the first step of the form.

On the safari popup window, select the Develop menu items and uncheck the "Disable javascript" option. [image]

If that option is not present:

- Pull down the “Safari” menu and choose “Preferences”
- Click on the “Advanced” tab.
- Check the box next to “Show Develop menu in menu bar”
- Close Preferences